# Hikari not closing connection

Tags: database, spring, hikaricp

I'm using Hikari with spring batch process. My job runs every 30 minutes and complete in 5 mins. After the job is completed I would expect the connection to be closed and returned to the pool for the next job. When I tried to do that, the 3rd or the 4th job usually throws out an error saying could not get connection. So I tried to create a new pool for every job and reduced the number of connections. But now, the connections just keeps growing and never gets killed. I can see there are many inactive connections but are not getting killed.

Here is the config:

```
   `<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" abstract="true" scope="prototype">
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="150000" />
    <property name="connectionTimeout" value="150000" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="300000"></property>
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="validationTimeout" value="10000"></property>
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="url" />
    </bean>`
```

Am I missing something here? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you measuring this?

Comment: I can check the number of connection in the database. I also enabled debug logging from Hikari and I don't see it closing.